# request.Files returns empty list

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, multi-upload

Try to upload multiples files using JQuery plugin in my django app (use bootstrap)- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

But I am facing a problem, in views.py the method called on "upload button". I receive the empty list of Files.

My code in views.py:-

```
def multiuploader(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'received POST to main multiuploader view'
        if request.FILES == None:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('Must have files attached!')
        print 'files'
        print request.FILES
```

In the console I get:

```
received POST to main multiuploader view 
files 
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

html file:-

```
<div id="fileupload">
<form action="{% url multi %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <label class="fileinput-button">
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
        <button type="reset" class="cancel">Cancel upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="fileupload-content">
    <table class="files"></table>
    <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

Any Idea how to solve this problem ??
Thanks alot in advnace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Multi-file upload not working on django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078441/jquery-multi-file-upload-not-working-on-django)

Comment: Use `is` instead of `==` to compare against `None`.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony that question has been removed.

Comment: @dokkaebi but this won't solve the problem, coz there are files that are actually sent !!

Comment: No, it won't. Just a side note. I really don't know what your problem is, but I suggest checking your browser's network traffic monitor or Fiddler to check that the browser is sending the files. If so, get as close to the request as you can on the server side -- maybe a breakpoint in the view's `dispatch` or a request middleware -- and see if the files have made it that far. That way you can narrow it down.